# 'Baby Driver' Tip Offs

Tags: plot-explanation, baby-driver

When we see Doc lay out both heist plans in *Baby Driver*, both schemes involve information or equipment provided by an insider with 'a nasal problem'.

What does this refer to? Is it an insinuation that Doc coerces cocaine dependants into helping him pull robberies or is it something else?

Comment: Since it's a crime movie, it's most likely cocaine

Comment: This is what I inferred from it - drugs for information / means to do the job

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This is most likely crime lingo, referring to a cocaine addiction**.

Cocaine is often snorted and sometimes referred to as ['nose candy'](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nose+candy). What he means is that they're basically exploiting someone's drug addiction (whether by supplying him the drugs or blackmailing him about it) to get him to help them. This is a fairly common trope with both criminals *and* cops (who would sometimes use a drug possession charge to flip witnesses).

To further corroborate this, notice that Buddy says he and Darling will be back for another job once their *'nose bag'* is empty - and Bats later explains exactly what that means:

> I know you guys got *noses to feed*... **You rob to support a drug habit.**

<sub>*[And as for this has something to do with Eddie No-Nose, don't ask me that!! ;)]*</sub>